# Get least significant digit including its value in a JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers

I would like to extract the least significant digit including its value from a number in JavaScript (so that no information is lost)

For example

`12.0123323` -> `0.0000003`

`123299000` -> `9000`

`123001` -> `1`

`123001.01` -> `0.01`

`10000000` -> `10000000`

etc...

Is there a neat way to do this?

Edit:
As people have noted because of Javascript:s way of handling numbers it can not represent 12.0123323, so let's assume it's a string in those corner cases.

Comment: You need to *define* what you mean by "least significant digit", since e.g. `12.0123323` isn't exactly represented. Maybe you can do that via some reasonable rounding rule. I would test whether default `toString` does the job, it might.

Comment: What have you tried? Is this homework?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/l/leastsd.htm I see, hmm but still it shows the right number of decimals when I print it in the console.

Comment: @Mottie No homework, just wonder if there is a standard solution before I brute force a solution.

Comment: This is unclear. In your second example, what makes `9000` the *least significant number* (it's four digits, not the *least significant digit* as your title describes). The *least significant digit* would be zero. (The same applies to the third and fifth examples, BTW, with one and zero respectively being the *least significant digits*.) And what makes `9000` the *least significant number* in #2, but `1` and not `3001` in #3?

Comment: @KenWhite Right, the least significant digit, including its value so that no information is lost. It will be a digit, with zeros to the right or the left. So we not only want the digit but also information about its size. Changed the title.

Comment: @user1506145: What Alf is getting at is that a floating-point value in JavaScript **cannot** have exactly the value 12.0123323. This is because JavaScript uses binary floating-point. The closest a floating-point value in JavaScript could be is 12.012332300000000628870111540891230106353759765625. But JavaScript may show you “12.0123323” by default. (I do not recall what the JavaScript defaults are for formatting numbers for output.) So what you think of as 12.0123323 is **not** 12.0123323, and the least significant digit of the true value is 5.

Comment: @user1506145: What this means is you have to clarify your question. If you have a numeral (a string of characters representing a number) rather than a floating-point number, you can examine the string to see what the least significant digit is. If you have a floating-point number, then either it is an integer or its least significant digit is 5. (When converted to decimal, all binary fractions end with 5.) If you know the floating-point number actually came from a decimal numeral with a limited number of digits, it may be possible to find the least significant digit of the original value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see, so let's assume we represent it as a string then for this corner case. You can still do stuff like `a  = 12.0123323`, `a+0.001`, `a.toString()` etc and it shows the correct result. However you can't do `a/10` it will give you `1.2012332300000002`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the value is an integer number and choose a different replacement schema for getting the right least significant value.

```js
function least(x) {
    return x === Math.floor(x)
        ? +x.toString().replace(/.*(?=[1-9]0*$)/, '')
        : +x.toString().replace(/\d(?=.*[1-9]$)/g, '0');

}

var array = [
        12.0123323, // 0.0000003
        123299000,  // 9000
        123001,     // 1
        123001.01,  // 0.01
        10000000    // 10000000
    ];

console.log(array.map(least));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const least = num => [...num.toString()].reduceRight((res, d, i) => (+res ? (d === "." ? "." : "0") : d) + res, "");
```

[Test Cases](http://jsbin.com/qobokeqixa/edit?console)

It basically traverses the string presentation (`toString`) of the number from right to left (`reduceRight`) and if the current result has already a digit in it (`+res`) then

```
  d === "." ? "." : "0"
```

it either takes over the dot or converts any other digit to 0. If there was no digit yet (`:`), it simply adds the current one `d`, and appends the already traversed part `+ res`

---

If you rather like readable code:

```
 function least(num){
  var res = "";
  for(var char of num.toString().split("").reverse()){
    if(+res){
      res = (char === "." ? "." : "0") + res;
    } else {
      res = char + res;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foundNonzero = false
Number("324.034"
.split('')
.reverse()
.map((i)=>{
    if(i==='.') return i
    if(foundNonzero) return '0'
    if(i!=='0'){
        foundNonzero = true 
    }
    return i
}).reverse().join(''))
```